# Problem on Elliptic Curve Point Doubling

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

Given an elliptical curve e.g. from “Understanding Cryptography” by Parr & Pelzl §9.2 Example 9.5:

$y^2 = x^3 + 2x + 2~~~~ mod~17$

And given a primitive $P = (5, 1)$, the book indicates:

> We compute now all the "powers" of P.

They then provide a table:

$2P = (5, 1) + (5, 1) = (6, 3)$

$3P = 2P + P = (10, 6)$

$...$

$18P = (5, 16)$

Unfortunately it is not apparent to me what action they are performing with the addition ($+$), or what they mean by "powers".  What operation is being performed to go from $(5, 1) + (5, 1)$ to $(6, 3)$, and so on?

The obvious operation (i.e. what Wolfram alpha does) of $(5, 1) + (5, 1) = (5 + 5, 1 + 1)$ yields $(10, 2)$.  There are a plethora of other possible combinations of operations that one could try, but I'd just be guessing.

Generally, given the secret, ordinarily labeled $d$, how ought one calculate $dP = P + P~ +~ ... ~+~ P$?

(This presumably computes the public key $X$ & $Y$ points, from $d$ and the $Gx$ and $Gy$ parameters)

While it is a rather core operation, and likely quite basic, I have found no illustrative examples and at-best convoluted implementations.  I'll keep looking, but I thought that a good answer might be a useful for the next person searching.

#### Edit

This exact example also appears and is discussed at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430836

Comment: [Point Doubling](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/elliptic/explicit.html)

Comment: @kelalaka Ahhhh, yes, that makes sense.

Comment: This question has been answered, but it might give some visibility to the next passers-along to keep this around, but I'm fine with it being deleted if that's preferred here.

Comment: post your calculation as an answer?

Comment: @kelalaka The best answer is probably a link to the `math` question that is virtually identical.  Unfortunately trivial answers are turned into comments  .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point addition $P+Q$ and doubling $2P = P +P $ in Elliptic Curves $E$ are not just x,y coordinates in the Euclidean Plane that you can add the coordinates. One can find the rules in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication);

> **Point addition:** With 2 distinct points, P and Q, addition is defined as the negation of the point resulting from the intersection of the curve, E, and the straight line defined by the points P and Q, giving the point, R.
>
> **Point doubling:** Where the points P and Q, are coincident (at the same coordinates), addition is similar, except that there is no well-defined straight line through P and Q, so the operation is closed using limiting case, the tangent to the curve, E, at P and Q.

---

Given the Elliptic curve $E:y^2= x^3+a x + b$ and a point $P=(x_p,y_p)$ on the curve, the doubling $R=2P = P + P$ can be calculated by:

\begin{align}
\lambda &= \frac{3 x_p^2 + a }{2 y_p}\\
x_r &= \lambda^2 -2 x_p\\
y_r &= \lambda(x_p-x_r) - y_p
\end{align}

The curve is defined in modular arithmetic $\pmod{17}$, therefore convert $1/2$ into $2^{-1} \equiv 9 \bmod 17$ and find the inverse by [extended GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) algorithm.

$\lambda = (3\cdot 5^2 +2)\cdot 9) \equiv 13 \bmod 17$

$x_r = \lambda^2 - 2 x_p  = (13^2  -10 ) \equiv 6 \bmod 17 $

$x_y = \lambda(x_p - x_r)-y_p =  13 \cdot ( 1 - 6) - 1 \equiv 3 \bmod 17$

$$(5,1) + (5,1) = (6,3)$$

Comment: The tricky part was the modular inverse i.e. 2^-1 = 9.

Comment: Because it's a Galois field, Fermat's Little Theorem can be used instead of extended GCD.

Answer (score 2):

#### I give a python program to clarify the above answer.

Given the Elliptic curve $E:y^2= x^3+2 x + 2 \pmod {17} , \#E=19$ and a primitive point $P=(x_p,y_p)=(5,1)$ on the curve. We calculate the $nP$

> ```
> # -*- coding:UTF-8
>
> # Extended Euclidean algorithm
> def extended_gcd(aa, bb):
>    lastremainder, remainder = abs(aa), abs(bb)
>    x, lastx, y, lasty = 0, 1, 1, 0
>    while remainder:
>        lastremainder, (quotient, remainder) = remainder, divmod(lastremainder, remainder)
>        x, lastx = lastx - quotient*x, x
>        y, lasty = lasty - quotient*y, y
>    return lastremainder, lastx * (-1 if aa < 0 else 1), lasty * (-1 if bb < 0 else 1)
>
> # calculate `modular inverse`
> def modinv(a, m):
>    g, x, y = extended_gcd(a, m)
>    if g != 1:
>        raise ValueError
>    return x % m
>
> # define the curve E: y^2 = x^3 + 2x + 2 (mod 17)  #E=19
> p = 17
> a = 2
> b = 2
> # the primitive point (x1,y1)=(5,1)
> x1 = x2 =5
> y1 = y2 = 1
> print str(1)+"P:\t", (x1, y1)
> for i in range(2, 19):
>    s = 0
>    if (x1 == x2):
>        # indentical point
>        s = ((3 * (x1 ** 2) + a) * modinv(2 * y1, p))%p
>    else:
>        # different points
>        s = ((y2 - y1) * modinv(x2 - x1, p))%p
>    # calculate i.P
>    x3 = (s ** 2 - x1 - x2) % p
>    y3 = (s*(x1 - x3) - y1) % p
>    print str(i) + "P:\t", (x3,y3)
>    (x2, y2) = (x3, y3)
> ```

Run this program, we can get the result:

> ```
> 1P:     (5, 1)
> 2P:     (6, 3)
> 3P:     (10, 6)
> 4P:     (3, 1)
> 5P:     (9, 16)
> 6P:     (16, 13)
> 7P:     (0, 6)
> 8P:     (13, 7)
> 9P:     (7, 6)
> 10P:    (7, 11)
> 11P:    (13, 10)
> 12P:    (0, 11)
> 13P:    (16, 4)
> 14P:    (9, 1)
> 15P:    (3, 16)
> 16P:    (10, 11)
> 17P:    (6, 14)
> 18P:    (5, 16)
> ```